# How can I make a multi-level(more than 3 level) navigation drawer in android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-navigation

I am developing an android application where I need to put a navigation drawer which would have more than 3 levels.

What I want to do: If I click one item of my list in the drawer, a whole new list comes up in the drawer. This new list should also do the same when items of this list are clicked. This could go on for many levels.

What I have done till now: I am keeping an expandable list which expands when I click on any item. This design doesn't allow adding more levels.

Application which have similar drawers: svpply (please have a look at this application, it has a similar drawer)

I am a newbie in android development, try to add details to your ideas.
Thanks!

Comment: Why not this "new list" comes up in new `Activity`?

Comment: Use `ExpandableListView` with custom `ExpandableListAdapter` and use that as your drawer item.

Comment: New list should come in the drawer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Have a single drawer keeping a FrameLayout.
- Make all your list as ListFragment
- Make Fragment Transaction on FrameLayout when a item is clicked.

Comment: Let me know if you still need more clarification to how to exactly do that what i stated above. There are several examples available on that on Google

Comment: Please share such example, I am very new to android development. Also, if you could, please take a look at svpply. I want to know how exactly they implemented the drawer design. Share the examples as well. Thank you! :)

Comment: Find the navigational drawer example at :https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html

What I would suggest is you can launch a DialogFragment with same XML UI format which is much simpler for every click the user makes, and you don't need keep track of backstack in fragment.

Comment: I've checked the svpply app. Its not a expandable list. Its pretty simple infact. Just prepare your all kind of lists separately as a subclass of ListFragment . And on specific click just change the fragment on framelayout present in drawer. That should do it. Search for google change fragment dyanmically.