# how to show image grid in a Drawer which has a listview inside it

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

In continuation with my last question
[How can I make a multi-level(more than 3 level) navigation drawer in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24300031/how-can-i-make-a-multi-levelmore-than-3-level-navigation-drawer-in-android/24300096#24300096)

What's happening: Basically I am showing filters in my navigation drawer which has children up to many levels. Whenever I click on any, it puts the selected filter at the top and shows its children below as a simple list.

What do I want: When I select a filter, I want to see the images of its children in a grid view inside the drawer(which is vertically scroll-able) just below the name of the filter. If an image is selected here, the name of this children gets added in the hierarchy list and I could see image grid of the new children. This could got upto many levels(safe to assume 4-5).

I was thinking I could make a fragment with same colors as that of the drawer and show my grid view inside it. But I lack much knowledge in it, how could I keep the fragment just below my list and inside the drawer.

Kindly provide a detailed solution. Android noob here.

Comment: Your requirements are not clear enough.
Make screenshot and simplify your problem to more.
yes you can not have grid view inside listview. Instead Look for HorizontalScrollView samples.
You can add those in list view.

Comment: And if every of your items including list items and images are suppose to scroll vertically only. Make all of them direct child of list only.

Comment: Okay, I will try to put in some pictures but what about the fragments. Could I create and destroy fragments which hold image grid views? Position of fragments should be defined pragmatically.