# Custom three level expandable list Android(each row different)

Tags: java, android, kotlin, expandablelistview

I need to create custom expandable list inside navigation view. At the beggining i needed only two level list, but now i must add new row with third level.

Does anyone know how to create something like this:

```
- clickable element without child
-group
 -clickable element without child
 -clickable element without child
-group
 -group2
  -clickable element without child
 -group2
  -clickable element without child
```

each clickable element does same action and same view.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24300031/how-can-i-make-a-multi-levelmore-than-3-level-navigation-drawer-in-android

Comment: i dont think so. I dont need Fragment Transaction. I would like to create element like regular expandable list. Answer from this link dosent fit my problem